# Do I need to create an endpoint?

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api, endpoints

Turns out **I'm trying to integrate witei's CRM into a website**. According to the witei documentation, **I must indicate a url (webhook)**, where I want to receive the information of the properties that has changed, so that I can keep the properties of my website updated.

The information is sent through the **POST method** and the service works because **it returns the data in JSON format**, testing through the https://beeceptor.com/ service (which generates a temporary endpoint).

The fact is that according to what I have read (or I understood), I have to create an endpoint in my Wordpress, following the steps indicated in the wordpress documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest- api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

My question is:
Am I in the right direction? If so ...
With my endpoint created, do I have to create any extra file? or just including the function 'register_rest_route', dont need to make anything else?
I have tried following instructions but I always get error 404.

[image]

The code involved for that is:

```
//Testing webhook
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'real-estate-lite/v1', '/endpoint', array(
    'methods'  => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
  ) );
} );

function my_awesome_func( $request ) {
     $data = $request->get_json_params();
     error_log( print_r( $data, true ) );
}
```

And in Witei CRM I get this result:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this? or just drive me in the right direction?
Thank you!

Comment: Try returning valid value. See https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#return-value

Comment: Sorry, I also tried that, in fact, is the first thing i did but wasn't successful. I have just modified the code.

Comment: Did you use the correct endpoint URL - `example.com/wp-json/real-estate-lite/v1/endpoint` ?

Comment: yes I do, and I have tried with several, but wasn't lucky

Comment: Looks like you are sending GET request. Please use POST.

Comment: ok. Just testing to see what happens, in the callback function a wrote **echo "hello"** and in witei platfrom says: request a JSON object and the answere is "hello" like the picture I have attached at the bottom. Does it makes sense?

Comment: I think I wasn't really paying attention to the details in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRCeg.png), so ignore my previous two comments. Have you tried to manually visit the endpoint (`example.com/wp-json/real-estate-lite/v1/endpoint`) using your browser? Are you sure it's giving you a 404 error?

Comment: Yes I did. Do I have to format with encode_json the variable? does the endpoint need to exist as a file? maybe is that why I get a 404 error. I am asking this because this error is saying that can't find the resource or am I wrong?

Comment: Plus I don't think it makes any sense if I manually visit the url, because the endpoint is only executed when I modify anything in the CRM. So..., maybe that is why everytime I visit the url I get a 404 error, but every time I make any change in the CRM, I get a response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I in the right direction?

Yes, and I'd also use the REST API if I were you.

> I have tried following instructions but I always get error 404.

That is actually normal *if* the request method is *not* POST — e.g. using the browser to manually access/visit the endpoint at `example.com/wp-json/real-estate-lite/v1/endpoint` whereby the (HTTP) request method is (or defaults to) GET.

And why it's normal is because the `methods` of your endpoint is set to `POST` *only* (i.e. `'methods'  => 'POST'`), hence all other request methods like GET are not allowed and therefore WordPress throws the error 404 when the endpoint is accessed through GET or another disallowed (HTTP) method.

So if for example you want GET method to be allowed, then set the `methods` to an array like so:

```php
register_rest_route( 'real-estate-lite/v1', '/endpoint', array(
    'methods'  => [ 'POST', 'GET' ], // allowed request methods
    'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
) );

/* The above code is equivalent to:
register_rest_route( 'real-estate-lite/v1', '/endpoint', array(
    // Endpoint 1, for POST request method.
    array(
        'methods'  => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    ),

    // Endpoint 2, for GET request method.
    array(
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func', // * the same callback
    ),
) );
*/
```

But of course, you wouldn't want to do that in your case since the webhook is using the POST method to connect to your custom WordPress REST API endpoint. For testing purposes though, you can temporarily allow GET requests (and then just go to the endpoint using your browser).

And as you can see in the example, we can have two or more endpoints at a route, and each request method should have its own callback.

BTW, sorry for not really understanding your issue/question earlier. :)